# External monitor image heavily distorted with red hues

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have been recently using an external monitor with my laptop for some time with no issues.  It is connected with a HDMI - > DVI cable.

Today I swapped this out with another monitor which did not work (I assumed it was bust) however when I went to plug the working monitor back in it only displays red/pink and flickers on and off.

These are the steps I've tried:

- Plugged the original monitor into another laptop

  - This works correctly proving the issue isn't the monitor nor cable
- Disabled the device and restarted
- Ran the troubleshoot hardware tool
- Updated the driver
- Used system restore to a time when it was working
- Plugged both monitors (same cable) into another laptop (both worked)

DXDiag output for the second monitor:

```
           Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
        Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
           Chip type: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
            DAC type: Internal
         Device Type: Full Device (POST)
          Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0166&SUBSYS_397717AA&REV_09
       Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER] 
 Device Problem Code: No Problem
 Driver Problem Code: Unknown
      Display Memory: 1792 MB
    Dedicated Memory: 0 MB
       Shared Memory: 1792 MB
        Current Mode: 1680 x 1050 (32 bit) (60Hz)
         HDR Support: Not Supported
    Display Topology: Extend
 Display Color Space: DXGI_COLOR_SPACE_RGB_FULL_G22_NONE_P709
     Color Primaries: Red(0.640148,0.330578), Green(0.300305,0.600109), Blue(0.150891,0.060070), White Point(0.313000,0.329602)
   Display Luminance: Min Luminance = 0.500000, Max Luminance = 270.000000, MaxFullFrameLuminance = 270.000000
        Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
       Monitor Model: SyncMaster
          Monitor Id: SAM044C
         Native Mode: 1680 x 1050(p) (59.883Hz)
         Output Type: HDMI
Monitor Capabilities: HDR Not Supported
Display Pixel Format: DISPLAYCONFIG_PIXELFORMAT_32BPP
      Advanced Color: Not Supported
         Driver Name: igdumdim64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll,igd10iumd64.dll
 Driver File Version: 10.18.0010.4358 (English)
      Driver Version: 10.18.10.4358
         DDI Version: 11.2
      Feature Levels: 11_0,10_1,10_0,9_3,9_2,9_1
        Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
 Graphics Preemption: DMA
  Compute Preemption: Thread group
            Miracast: Supported
 Hybrid Graphics GPU: Integrated
      Power P-states: Not Supported
      Virtualization: Not Supported
          Block List: No Blocks
  Catalog Attributes: N/A
   Driver Attributes: Final Retail
    Driver Date/Size: 21/12/2015 01:00:00, 11157656 bytes
         WHQL Logo'd: Yes
     WHQL Date Stamp: Unknown
   Device Identifier: {D7B78E66-4226-11CF-1C65-7D19B4C2C735}
           Vendor ID: 0x8086
           Device ID: 0x0166
           SubSys ID: 0x397717AA
         Revision ID: 0x0009
  Driver Strong Name: oem4.inf:5f63e5341859ec8c:iIVBM_w10:10.18.10.4358:pci\ven_8086&dev_0166
      Rank Of Driver: 00D12001
         Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C ModeWMV9_C ModeVC1_C 
         DXVA2 Modes: DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_VLD  DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_IDCT  DXVA2_ModeVC1_D2010  DXVA2_ModeWMV9_IDCT  DXVA2_ModeVC1_IDCT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT  
   Deinterlace Caps: {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
                     {BF752EF6-8CC4-457A-BE1B-08BD1CAEEE9F}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_EdgeFiltering 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY VideoProcess_AlphaBlend 
        D3D9 Overlay: Supported
             DXVA-HD: Supported
        DDraw Status: Enabled
          D3D Status: Enabled
          AGP Status: Enabled
       MPO MaxPlanes: 1
            MPO Caps: Not Supported
         MPO Stretch: Not Supported
     MPO Media Hints: Not Supported
         MPO Formats: Not Supported
    PanelFitter Caps: Not Supported
 PanelFitter Stretch: Not Supported
```

And finally a lovely picture showing my blight:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks as if the broken monitor destroyed the HDMI port on your laptop.
But the only way to know that for sure is to try a 3rd monitor with your laptop. If that gives a bad picture too the HDMI port of your laptop is bust.
(If the laptop has multiple video-outputs (like DisplayPort, Thunderbolt) these might be affected too, but you could be lucky and some of those still work.)

For your sake I hope that the laptop is still under warranty because this usually means replacing the entire motherboard, which is usually so expensive a new laptop might be a better option than a repair.
If you send it in for repair don't be too specific about the cause. Don't mention you connected it to another monitor. Just say it stopped working. Some vendors might attempt to wiggle out of a warranty claim saying it is your own fault. But a monitor should not be able to short out the laptop like that. Unfortunately may laptops don't have proper surge-protection on the ports.

If it is not under warranty anymore check your insurance. It might be covered under that, but don't expect to get full value for the laptop.

Comment: Although I'd be inclined to agree it appears that both monitors (same cable) work with an entirely different laptop.  So the only possibility is damaged port (through whatever reason) or driver issues.  I can't believe the port would be damaged through swapping a monitor over though (something I just did with the other laptop)

Comment: @m.edmondson Swapping monitors shouldn’t damage a port, but I’ve seen it happen once in a while. Usually when pc and monitor are both on while plugging the cable in and  there is a lot of static electricity around.